# Entity Framework can't generate database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework code-first and working on a simple HRM project.

My data model class:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My context class:

```
public class HumanResourceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

To generate the database in my home controller `Index` action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome";

        using (var context = new HR.DataModel.DAL.HumanResourceContext())
        {
            var query = from e in context.Employees select e;

            foreach (HR.DataModel.Entities.Employee e  in query)
            {
                ViewBag.Message += e.Name + ", ";
            }
        }

        return View();
}
```

Now when I run this I get this error:

> Cannot attach the file 'D:\Projects\HRSystem\HR.Web\App_Data\HR.DataModel.DAL.HumanResourceContext.mdf' as database 'HR.DataModel.DAL.HumanResourceContext'.

What am I doing wrong? Help please. I tried finding the solution to this. But couldn't get this. Thanks

Comment: Check this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1768918.aspx) `I would try giving the database a different name. Sometimes you can run into problems with SQL Express when trying to create a database with the same name a second time. There is a way to fix this using SQL Server Management Studio but it's generally easier to just use a different database name.`

Comment: I didnt get that sir

Comment: My connection string   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HR.Web-20151028044136.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HR.Web-20151028044136;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Remove this line `"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|-xxxxxxxxxx.mdf"`

Comment: Again same error sir..

Comment: Are you connecting to local db?

Comment: if it's true then remove `Initial Catalog` property and add removed `attachdbfilename` ex: `<connectionStrings> <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HR.Web-201‌​51028044136.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>`

Comment: I am following a simple step by step HRSystem tutorial sir..and like what the the error said..there is no .mdf file in  myD:\Projects\HRSystem\HR.Web\App_Data\HR.DataModel.DAL.HumanResourceContext.mdf..

Comment: clicking the "show all files" icon in the Solution Explorer. By default the .mdf file will not show up, so ensure the "show all files" is selected .and also check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257(v=vs.100).ASPX) about connection strings

Comment: After clicking "show all files" the app_data folder is still empty sir..

Comment: I changed the name <add name> to "HumanResourceContext" and its working now sir.

Comment: Point of order: do not add relevant information like ConnectionStrings in comments, _edit_ the question body and improve it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Got that.Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Initial Catalog` property and add removed attachdbfilename ex:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HR.Web-201‌​‌​51028044136.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Try to Change Name `<add name>`
 and Some Reference [links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257(v=vs.100).ASPX) related to connection strings

Comment: if you obbserve this line   `using (var context = new HR.DataModel.DAL.HumanResourceContext())` here you are using the connection name as `HumanResourceContext` but you were give `Default Connection` in your connection so these both were contradicting and raised you error!!